# How to add inertia to object 3d in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I create a game and I need use inertia for object.

**Example:**

[image: GAMEIMAGE]

The image shows all what I need.
When I touch on screen, blueObject no longer uses the position of brownObject and rotation of redObject. And I add component Rigidbody. The object just falls down. I need him to fall further along his trajectory (inertia).

I tried to use `addForce(transform.forward * float)`, this not work.

Comment: RigidBodys always act independently unless `Joint`-ed (parenting doesn't count).  See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the position of the transform, you don't use Unity Physics engine. Your cube must have a rigidbody from the begin of the simulation and what you need here is a spring joint (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint.html) or a fixed joint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the current speed, when releasing the object.

Track the positions over the last frame & current frame, and use `Time.deltaTime` to compensate different frame-rates.

Then set this velocity to your objects rigidbody. (AddForce is just manipulating the velocity, but depending on the ForceMode it respects mass etc.)

```
public Vector3 lastPosition = Vector3.zero;

void Update()
{
    // maybe do : if(lastPosition != Vector3.zero) to be sure



    Vector3 obj_velocity = (lastPosition - transform.position) * Time.deltaTime;
    lastPosition = transform.position;

    // if you release the object, do your thing, add rigidbody, then:
    rb.velocity = obj_velocity; 
}
```

That should create the "inertia". the velocity contains the direction and the speed.